# Is it possible for traits to impose restrictions for references to the type it is implemented on?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a generic function that halves `Integer`s. For the record, I know that there is a `num_integer::Integer` trait, and I am using it in my real code.

For the sake of halving, the only operations my `Integer` requires is the ability to shift a reference to the right and a one value. I want to use `Integer`s in a lot of places, so I capture these two traits in my `Integer` trait and provide a generic implementation for it. However, I'm still required to specify `std::ops::Shr` for my `half` function.

I am aware of two workarounds for this problem. One is to specify `std::ops::Shr` everywhere:

```
extern crate num_traits;

pub trait Integer
where
    Self: num_traits::One,
    for<'a> &'a Self: std::ops::Shr<Self, Output = Self>,
{
}

impl<T> Integer for T
where
    T: num_traits::One,
    for<'a> &'a T: std::ops::Shr<T, Output = T>,
{
}

fn half<N: Integer>(n: &N) -> N
where
    for<'a> &'a N: std::ops::Shr<N, Output = N>, // Would like to get rid of this line!
{
    n >> num_traits::one()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", half(&85));
}
```

Another option is to have `half` consume its argument instead of borrowing it, in which case I'm shifting values instead of references and the offending commented line is no longer necessary:

```
extern crate num_traits;

pub trait Integer
where
    Self: num_traits::One,
    Self: std::ops::Shr<Self, Output = Self>,
{
}

impl<T> Integer for T
where
    T: num_traits::One,
    T: std::ops::Shr<T, Output = T>,
{
}

fn half<N: Integer>(n: N) -> N {
    n >> num_traits::one()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", half(85));
}
```

Is there some other alternative I haven't considered?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I think [Implied bounds (RFC 2089)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44491) is supposed to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative would be to move the function to a trait method:

```
pub trait Integer
where
    Self: num_traits::One,
    for<'a> &'a Self: std::ops::Shr<Self, Output = Self>,
{
    fn half(&self) -> Self {
        self >> num_traits::one()
    }
}
```

This doesn't *really* solve the core problem, but it does allow you to avoid writing that bound yet another time.